# What is the real meaning of "Kanyadhana"

Tags: marriage, manu-smriti

I have read at a Hinduism website ([Website Link](https://www.madhava.net/hindu-marriage-tradition-the-real-meaning-of-kanyadana/)) that the word "Kanyadhaana" is misinterpreted into meaning "Donating the bride"

According to the web article:

> It's not "Kanya-Dhaana" but "Kanya-Aadhana"
>
> Here, Kanya means "Daughter/Girl"
> And Aadhana means "receive"
> So basically "Kanyadhaana" translates  to "**Receiving the bride**" and NOT "**Donating the bride**".

Women's rights activists argue that Kanyadhaana means donating the bride and girls being humans are not objects/ commodities  that can be "donated" to the groom's family.

I'm confused here. What is the real meaning of Kanyadhaana? Is it "Kanya-aadhana" or "Kanya-dhaana" itself?

Comment: it is kanya-daan. the bride is donated. the reward for donating a kanya to a vaidika brahmachari groom is brahma-loka

Comment: if u relay meant the word used in Q title i.e. **Kanyadhana** then it's meaning is **[girl's patrimonial riches](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28421/12304)**..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is KanyA dAna and not what you said also it is not DH but D..

See [Manu Smriti 3.29](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199804.html):

> एकं गोमिथुनं द्वे वा वरादादाय धर्मतः ।
>   **कन्याप्रदानं** विधिवदार्षो धर्मः स उच्यते ॥ २९ ॥
>
> ekaṃ gomithunaṃ dve vā varādādāya dharmataḥ |
>   **kanyāpradānaṃ** vidhivadārṣo dharmaḥ sa ucyate || 29 ||
>
> ‘**When the maiden is given away** in due accordance with rule, after
>   taking, in odedience to law, from the bridegroom, one or two pairs of
>   cow and bull,—this is called the “Ārṣa” form.’—(29).

KanyA DAna and KanyA PradAna of course have the same meaning.

Comment: "A bride is given to the groom's family and that family gives a pair of cow or bull to the bride's family." regarding that statement what is the right way to interpret that statement? Should I interpret it as- a girl is given to the groom's family and the family gives the bull as a "present" to the bride's family. Or should I interpret it as the girl is exchanged for cow or bull? Feminists state the later interpretation and argue that since a girl is exchanged for bull she is treated as a commodity and this way Manu Smriti objectifies women. So please tell me how do I interpret that statement.

Comment: No it's not an exchange by any means .. it is just a part of the rituals .. @Somanna

Comment: @Somanna And Dharma is represented as bull in Hindu scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

Kanyadhana (कन्याधन) means Kanya's Dhana (girl's property)  or "patrimonial riches" or girl's share in her parents' property.

This is given in [Valmiki Ramayana: Bala Kanda: Sarga 74](http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/baala/sarga74/bala_74_frame.htm):

> अथ राजा विदेहानां ददौ **कन्याधनं** बहु |
>
> Then that king Janaka of Mithila, the one from Videha lineage, gave innumerable **patrimonial riches**.

---

Related: [Which practice existed during the reign of Lord Rama, either Kanyasulkam or Varakatnam(Dowry)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/which-practice-existed-during-the-reign-of-lord-rama-either-kanyasulkam-or-vara/28421#28421)